# Why Does the "Quit" Button Stop Working After the "No" Button is Clicked?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, destroy, toplevel

I have a "Quit" button that creates a Toplevel window to ask if user is sure about quitting.  If the "No" button is clicked, the window is destroyed, but the "Quit" button no longer works.  Uh, the "quitter" virtual event keystrokes (CTRL-Q, Q, and CTRL-C) also stop functioning.  Why is that?

```
from Tkinter import *

class ButtonTestClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.title("No Button Tester!")

        self.root.option_add('*font', ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
        self.frame=Frame(self.root, height=120, width=600, \
            borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE, background='steelblue'
            )
        self.frame.pack(fill=X, expand=False)
        self.frame.pack_propagate(False)

        self.label = Label(self.frame, \
            text='Why does the "Quit" button stop working\nafter the "No" button is clicked?', bg='steelblue')
        self.label.pack(padx=25, pady=15, side=TOP)

        self.root.event_add('<<ev_quit>>', '<Control-c>', '<Control-q>', '<q>')
        self.root.bind('<<ev_quit>>', lambda e: self.bye_bye())

        self.byeWindow = None
        print "In constructor self.byeWindow -  value: '%r' type: '%r'" % (self.byeWindow, type(self.byeWindow))  # <<< DEBUG >>>

    def createQuitButton(self):
        pbx=250; pby=70; pbw=75; pbh=25; pbp=10
        self.quitBtn=Button(self.frame, text='Quit', activebackground='steelblue3', font='arial 10 bold', bg='steelblue', command=lambda: self.bye_bye())
        self.quitBtn.place(x=pbx, y=pby, width=pbw, height=pbh)
        pbx += pbw + pbp

    def dontQuit(self, tlref):
        self.byeWindow = None   # <<<--- There was a 'misspelling' here; grrrr!
        tlref.destroy()
        print "In dontQuit(). self.byeWindow - value: '%r' type: '%r'" % (self.byeWindow, type(self.byeWindow))  # <<< DEBUG >>>

    def bye_bye(self):
        if self.byeWindow is not None:
            return
        self.byeWindow=Toplevel()
        print "In bye_bye(), self.byeWindow - value: '%r' type: '%r'" % (self.byeWindow, type(self.byeWindow))  # <<< DEBUG >>>
        self.byeWindow.title("Really quit?")
        self.byeWindow.config(bg='steelblue', height=40, width=80)
        sureMsgLabel=Label(self.byeWindow, text="Are you sure you want to quit?", font='arial 11 bold', bg='steelblue')
        sureMsgLabel.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=15)
        yesButton=Button(self.byeWindow, text=" Yes. ", font='arial 10 bold', bg='steelblue', activebackground='steelblue3', command=lambda: quit())
        yesButton.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N, padx=40, pady=20)
        yesButton.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda: yesButton.invoke())
        noButton = Button(self.byeWindow, text="  No. ", activebackground='steelblue3', font='arial 10 bold', bg='steelblue', command=lambda: self.dontQuit(self.byeWindow))
        noButton.focus_force()
        noButton.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=N, padx=40, pady=20)
        noButton.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda: noButton.invoke())

bT = ButtonTestClass()

bT.createQuitButton()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bT.root.mainloop()
```

P.S. If you run this snippet, you will see what I mean, in case I haven't described the issue clearly.  Ta ...

Comment: This question is way too wordy, considering the actual question boils down to "I have a button connected to a function that destroys a window, but it doesn't destroy the window. Why is that?".

Comment: You are right, Mr. Oakley.  Mea culpa!  I'll be more concise going forward.

Comment: I had misspelled my instance variable name (byWindow, instead of byeWindow), which caused my if condition to to be True, resulting in a return, which meant that the Toplevel window did not get created.  Correcting the misspelling, fixed the problem.  Thank you Bryan Oakley, for your insightful tips and comments.  I shall endeavor to "pay it forward"!

Comment: you completely changed your question after a couple answers were given. That makes it very confusing to people coming here for answers.

Comment: Well, you said it was too wordy, so I "briefified" it!  Was I just supposed to ignore your assertion?

Comment: you "briefified" it, then applied my suggestions and asked a different question. My answer no longer made any sense because I suggested you add things that are now part of the question. Your question was about why the No button didn't work at all (IIRC), but now it asks why using it causes the Quit button to stop working. Those are two different problems.

Comment: Oops, again you are right. I was trying, per your comment,  to fix "the way I asked my question" even though it was ultimately all about the same problem, but I guess I just made things more obfuscated and less "sensical" (yeah, I like making up new words)  Well, at least you come out looking like a hero and sounding intelligent.  I'm at least happy about that!  (:>)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in the final analysis my problem was a misspelling of an instance variable: "byWindow" instead of "byeWindow", which ballocked up the if statement in my self.bye_bye() function.  Correcting the spelling fixed the problem.  Many thanks and kind regards to Bryan Oakley for his insightful tips and sage advice.  Here is the flawlessly running program ...

```
from Tkinter import *

class ButtonTestClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.title("Button Tester!")

        self.root.option_add('*font', ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
        self.frame=Frame(self.root, height=120, width=600, \
            borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE, background='steelblue'
            )
        self.frame.pack(fill=X, expand=False)
        self.frame.pack_propagate(False)

        self.label = Label(self.frame, \
            text='Wanna see a "Quit" button working flawlessly?', bg='steelblue')
        self.label.pack(padx=25, pady=15, side=TOP)

        self.root.event_add('<<ev_quit>>', '<Control-c>', '<Control-q>', '<q>')
        self.root.bind('<<ev_quit>>', lambda e: self.bye_bye())

        self.byeWindow = None

    def createQuitButton(self):
        pbx=250
        pby=70
        pbw=75
        pbh=25
        pbp=10
        self.quitBtn=Button(
            self.frame, 
            text='Quit', 
            activebackground='steelblue3',
            font='arial 10 bold',
            bg='steelblue',
            command=self.bye_bye
        )
        self.quitBtn.place(
            x=pbx, 
            y=pby, 
            width=pbw, 
            height=pbh
        )
        pbx += pbw + pbp

    def dontQuit(self, tlref):
        tlref.destroy()
        self.byeWindow = None

    def bye_bye(self):
        if self.byeWindow is not None:
            return
        self.byeWindow=Toplevel()
        self.byeWindow.title("Really quit?")
        self.byeWindow.config(bg='steelblue', height=40, width=80)
        sureMsgLabel=Label(self.byeWindow, 
            text="Are you sure you want to quit?", 
            font='arial 11 bold',
            bg='steelblue'
        )
        sureMsgLabel.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=15)
        yesButton=Button(self.byeWindow,
            text=" Yes. ",
            font='arial 10 bold',
            bg='steelblue',
            activebackground='steelblue3',
            command=lambda: quit()
        )
        yesButton.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N, padx=40, pady=20)
        yesButton.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda: yesButton.invoke())
        noButton = Button(self.byeWindow, 
            text="  No. ",
            activebackground='steelblue3',
            font='arial 10 bold',
            bg='steelblue',
            command=lambda: self.dontQuit(self.byeWindow)
        )
        noButton.focus_force()
        noButton.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=N, padx=40, pady=20)
        noButton.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda: noButton.invoke())

bT = ButtonTestClass()

bT.createQuitButton()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bT.root.mainloop()
```

Well, it's not really a program, per se, but rather a few lines extracted from a program that had a "button not working" problem.  Cheers!